# How can i generate Angular components provided by an external library using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-deployment, primeng

I'm working on a Angular project and I am making use of an external component library (**NGPrime**: https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/) which provides me some built-in components such as `<p-button>` (that i use instead of normal `<button>`).

I now want to create a new `<p-button>` each time the user fires an event. I simply tried with

```
var button = document.createElement('p-button')
document.getElementById("button-list").appendChild(button)
```

and

```
document.getElementById("button-list").innerHTML += '<p-button>Click Me!</p-button>'
```

But of course nothing works.

How can i dynamically generate new `<p-button>`?

Comment: Keep a count of the buttons you want to display, use ```*ngFor``` to render them, up the counter on user event accordingly

Comment: @sinanspd unfortunately buttons aren't all equals: i have to inject specific attributes depending on the different action of the user

Comment: Can you update the question with an example? I still believe this is achievable with an ngFor, you can create an object that holds these properties, push it into an array and build based on that

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to use innerHtml

> ```
>     <div class="one" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div>
>           this.htmlToAdd = '<div class="two">two</div>';
> ```

2. Alternatively

> ```
>     <div class="one" #one></div>
> ```
>
> And in component
>
> ```
>      @ViewChild('one') d1:ElementRef;
>
>      ngAfterViewInit() {
>          d1.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div 
>               class="two">two</div>');
>      }
> ```

or to prevent direct DOM access:

> ```
>  constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {}
>
>  @ViewChild('one') d1:ElementRef;
>
>  ngAfterViewInit() {
>      this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.d1.nativeElement', 
>         'insertAdjacentHTML' ['beforeend', '<div class="two">two</div>']);
>  }
> ```

  3.

> ```
>     constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}
>
>     ngAfterViewInit() {
>        var d1 = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.one');
>        d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="two">two</div>');
>      }
> ```